# How do you run the code without external computer in BeagleBone Black just by powering it?

Tags: beaglebone-black

For example, an autonomous robot. The code should execute once I apply the power supply to BeagleBone Black without having it connected to the computer. I am using angstrom distro.

Comment: You have Linux on the BBB?  Google "Linux init scripts"

Comment: There have been lots of ways of doing this in different Linux configurations, you'll need one suitable to the unspecified distro you are actually using.

Comment: I am using angstrom distro.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian, see: [Making Scripts Run at Boot_Time With Debian](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian)
(add script to /etc/init.d, run `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/foobar.sh`, then `update-rc.d foobar.sh`)

For Angstrom, see: [Setting Up Boot Scripts For Beaglebone Angstrom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45940/setting-up-boot-scripts-for-beaglebone-angstrom)